# IBM Reason Code 2009 when attempting to connect to external host .net

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm very new to IBM MQ and feel like I'm missing something fairly easy.

I received the following files and I'm attempting to connect to an externally hosted MQ:

- .crl
- .kdb
- .rdb
- .sth
- .tab

I've tried several different approaches, but the "furthest" I think I've gotten is:
`MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN Reason: 2009` when I attempt to create a new Queue Manager connection.

Below is my most recent block of code, trying to get this to work:

```cs
using IBM.WMQ;
...

Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, SOME_ADDRESS);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, SOME_CHANNEL);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, SOME_PORT);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, PATH TO KDB FILE without .kdb);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, SOME_CIPHER);

MQQueueManager qmgr = new MQQueueManager(SOME_VALUE, connectionProperties);
```

Prior to this I was attempting to set the `MQ_CHANNEL_LIB` and `MQ_CHANNEL_TAB` environment variables and call `MQQueueManager qmgre = MQQueueManager()` but that resulted in a 2277 error code.

I'm currently using the `IBMMQDotnetClient/9.3.0` nuget package. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The *.kdb file is a ssl keystore file containing certificates required to connect to queue manager. The *.kdb file can only be used with Transport type (TRANSPORT_PROPERTY property) MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT. In this mode, MQ .NET client uses MQI C client underneath to communicate with queue manager.

The *.tab file is a client channel definition table (CCDT) file containing connection information like qm name, channel name, host name and few others required to connect to your queue manager.

Since you are using IBMMQDotnetClient/9.3.0 nuget package, TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT transport type can't be used as the package doesn't contain MQI C client. With this nuget package you can only use TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED. Ask your admins/management if they can provide you [Redistributable MQ client](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=overview-redistributable-mq-clients). This package contains MQI C, .NET and other MQ clients libraries. You can choose to install the client libraries you want to use.

Comment: Shashi, thank you very much for the quick response. With the redistributable MQ libraries needing to be installed; will this be useable in a serverless cloud configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used word "install". Redistributable client is an unzippable package. Just unpack the libraries to a suitable directory, set path accordingly and use. The libraries can be packaged and redistributed with your application.

Comment: Are you running it on windows or Linux containers?

Comment: If it's on windows you can extract the certs and load then in the windows cert store.   If it is Linux you can convert them to pkcs12 format.

Comment: @JoshMc is it a requirement to load / convert the certs even with the kdb file?

Comment: Sashi's answer already explained that kdb is only for unmanaged .NET.  If you want to use .NET standard then you can't use the kdb.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @Shashi does IBM provide an example of using the unmanaged libraries in .net to connect to an MQ using the .kdb, .tab files etc. All examples provided seem to use username/password combinations or managed connections to connect.  Ultimately, I'm trying to make an unmanaged IBM MQ application that will run on a cloud provider that will use the above-mentioned files to connect to a queue. I've downloaded the redistributable but I'm not seeing any clear indication in what libraries to use in order to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You would need .NET and MQ C client. There is a genmqpkg executable shipped with the package. After you unpack the package, you can run genmqpkg and choose .NET and MQC client.

Comment: Here is link:https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=windows-redistributable-clients

Answer (score 0):

As Shashi mentioned if you need to use the Unmanaged mode,you need MQ C Client libraries as well.
You need to reference "amqmdnet.dll" which comes with IBM MQ Redistributable package to your .NET project. You can download IBM MQ Redistributable package from [IBM Fix central](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EWebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20MQ&release=9.2.0.0&platform=All&function=fixid&fixids=*IBM-MQC-Redist-*).

To use CCDT, you need to set MQCHLLIB & MQCHLTAB environment variables.On how to create a CCDT file you can refer KC page:[Configuring a binary format CCDT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=tables-configuring-binary-format-ccdt)

After creating the CCDT File, i had used only the following code in my project to establish a successful connection

```
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QMSSL\@ipcc");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", "AMQCLCHL.TAB");
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQSSLKEYR", @"C:\temp\Certs\ForCclient\client");
        try
        {
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
        }
        catch (MQException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR - Connect failed with unexpected MQRC {0}", e.ReasonCode);
            throw e;
        }
```